# Проблема с расшифровкой cookie и SQL запросом

Tags: php, cookie, mysql

Доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с непонятной проблемой.
Проблема заключается вот в чём, у меня есть зашифрованный `login`, который содержется в `cookie`, я произвожу его расшифровку следующим методом (зашифровка почти по той же схеме):

```
function decoding($text){
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_get_iv_size (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $key = "This is a very secret key";
    $decrypt_name = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $decrypt_name;
}
```

Далее у меня есть следующий кусок кода:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$login = decoding($_COOKIE['login']);
$password = decoding($_COOKIE['password']);
$db_server = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", $login, $password);
...
mysql_select_db("customer_base", $db_server);
$result = mysql_query("set names UTF-8");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT manager.ip FROM manager WHERE manager.login='".$login."'");
...
```

К `MySQL` он подключается, всё хорошо, но при запросе к таблице manager ничего не приходит, хотя запись в этой таблице существует. В чём может быть проблема, может быть в кодировке? (При запросе никаких ошибок не происходит).

Comment: А не пробовали вывести "SELECT manager.ip FROM manager WHERE manager.login='".$login."'", а потом этот запрос ручками в MySQL ввести?

Может тогда сами проблему увидите?

Ну и подключаться к консоли лучше используя тот же логин, что и в PHP

Comment: Я пробовал через phpMyAdmin, запрос проходил. Спасибо, но я уже пошёл по другому пути:)

Answer (score 1):

А это весь код? Вывод с базы можно сделать так:

```
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($r['ip'] == true)
  echo $r['ip'];
```

Или еще проще не выводит, а посчитать количество совпадений в таблице ;-). Удачи Вам!

Comment: Спасибо за удачу) Дело в том что полученный результат я использую, а количество приходящих строк равно нулю, хотя должно быть равно 1(запись в БД есть).
Мне кажется вся проблема в ...WHERE manager.login='".$login."'"...
а точнее в $login.
Для примера: $login у меня равен 'user', к mysql подключается, а вот запрос не проходит..

Comment: Если хотите можете добавить меня в скайп попробую помочь. Мой логин: node_xaker